# When opening spyder: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I'm working with **anaconda3** and **python3.8.10**. At first when I tried to open spyder and it would close straight away, so I reinstalled it and have the following problem.
When I try to open spyder(versions 4.2.5---->5.0.3) I get the following error message **ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.** It prompts me to install some "missing dependencies",**jedi = 0.17.2 : 0.18.0** and **parso = 0.7.0 : 0.8.2**. I installed these packages restarted spyder, anaconda and my computer, and still, I get the error when opening. I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda and I still get the same error. I tried creating a different environment with different versions of python and spyder, no luck.
I have  also tried all of the following:

- conda install pywin32
- conda unsinstall spyder, conda install spyder

when I run conda uninstall and install spyder I get the following message.
**
/ DEBUG menuinst_win32:**init**(198): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\envs\IEEE_COMP_ENV', env_name: 'IEEE_COMP_ENV', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\envs\IEEE_COMP_ENV', 'C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\envs\IEEE_COMP_ENV\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\envs\IEEE_COMP_ENV\Scripts\spyder-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\envs\IEEE_COMP_ENV', 'C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\envs\IEEE_COMP_ENV\python.exe', 'C:\Users\noah\anaconda3\envs\IEEE_COMP_ENV\Scripts\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
done
**